# Can I deploy Azure webjobs as a IoT Edge modules?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-iot-edge

I have this webjob in azure which saves the telemetry data and processed it for given condition(for example- Temperature exceeds the given threshold), I want to deploy this web-job as a IoT Edge module in my IoT Hub. Is It possible?

If yes, Can I get some links to the required information?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot deploy a Webjob directly onto IoT Edge. However, depending on how your application works, you might be able to transfer or re-use the code quite easily into either an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function) or into a [custom module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module).

Does this help in your case?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped to solve your problem.